# Codeception - Sending a file via REST sendPost

Tags: php, codeception

first of all, I am almost completely new to programming and completely new to codeception and PHP.

I'm wondering if anyone could help me with how I use codeception to send a file using the sendPost method in the REST module http://codeception.com/docs/modules/REST#sendPOST .

The help file describes sending it via an array but honestly can't figure it out.

The most sensible way I can come up with is the following

```
$I->sendPost(array("filename"))
```

Like I said, completely new at this.

The file is located in the directory that Codeception has been installed hence why I didn't think I needed to specify it's location. I'm also aware of how to send a Post without an attached file, just not one with an attached file.

I hope that's enough information.

Apologies if it isn't.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Send file to Restful service in codeception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28437633/send-file-to-restful-service-in-codeception)

Answer (score 8):

I would put the file into the tests/_data directory, and then get the path to it using codecept_data_dir:

```
$I->sendPOST('/my-endpoint', ['field' => 'value'], [ 'someFile' => codecept_data_dir('file.png')]);
```

Comment: It's possible to set name of upload? Not filename, but field name.

Answer (score 1):

I tried the approach suggested by Jesper Jonsson, but it didn't work for me. After browsing the source code of Codeception framework, I worked out another solution described in my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28437633/send-file-to-restful-service-in-codeception/32849920#32849920). Briefly, you should put a mock of $_FILES array as the third argument to sendPOST().